# How to calculate average distance of all samples element in a dataset

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to calculate the average distance of samples in a dataset. the aim is to calculate the distance between the sample, sum them and multiply by (2/n(n-1)), where n is the total number of sample in the dataset.

I have been trying to figure this out, but am new to it so im stuck

This is how i approach the problem but is not given me the expected result. please i need your assistance

```
def euclidean_distance(array1, array2):
return sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip(array1, array2))**0.5

data  = [[1,2,3], [6,4,5], [8,9,10], [6,7,8]]
data1 = data[1:]
list_distance = []
for i in data:
   for j in data1:
      list_distance.append(euclidean_distance(i, j))

print(list_distance)      
summation = sum(list_distance)

mean_distance = (2/(len(data)*(len(data)-1)))*summation

print("The total distance is "+ str(summation))
print("The mean distance is "+ str(mean_distance))
```

Expected Output:

```
[5.744562646538029, 12.12435565298214, 8.660254037844387, 7.3484692283495345, 
4.242640687119285, 3.4641016151377544]
The total distance is 41.58438386797113
The mean distance is 6.930730644661855
```

Output from my code

```
[5.744562646538029, 12.12435565298214, 8.660254037844387, 0.0, 7.3484692283495345, 4.242640687119285, 
7.3484692283495345, 0.0, 3.4641016151377544, 4.242640687119285, 3.4641016151377544, 0.0]
The total distance is 56.63959539857771
The mean distance is 9.439932566429619
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use itertools for combinations of data elements:

```
def euclidean_distance(array1, array2):
    return sum((x-y)**2 for x, y in zip(array1, array2))**0.5


data  = [[1,2,3], [6,4,5], [8,9,10], [6,7,8]]

list_distance = []

import itertools

for x,y in itertools.combinations(data,2):
    list_distance.append(euclidean_distance(x,y))

print(list_distance)      
summation = sum(list_distance)

mean_distance = (2.0/(len(data)*(len(data)-1)))*summation

print("The total distance is "+ str(summation))
print("The mean distance is "+ str(mean_distance))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing some pairs twice (a,b & b,a), and some pairs you've made from the same point twice.  This fixes both problems:

```
for ix,i in enumerate(data):
   for j in data[ix+1:]:
      list_distance.append(euclidean_distance(i, j))
```

Also, I'm sure there's something in `itertools` that you could use.

Comment: that is exactly what i am doing. i try your suggestion and it works but can you suggest better solution. thanks

Comment: I don't understand your comment; your code produced the wrong result, and this does not, so it is not "exactly what [you are] doing".  In what way(s) would you want it improved?

Comment: sorry, what i am trying to say was that , the problem you highlighted in your first comment about doing some pairs twice is exactly what is happening to my code but with your suggestion has solve the problem know. thanks for that. if i want to improve in terms of speed because what i am working on is a big data problem.

Comment: If you don't need the list of distances, you can accumulate the sum & divide by the count to get the mean.  You could also try numpy, which has tools just for such numeric computations.